# Solving for current flowing through R and reflection coefficient

Tags: circuit-analysis, transmission-line, homework

This is my attempt at solving it. I'm not sure if it's correct, so I thought of asking for some advice.

Image of circuit:
[image]

Values:
[image]

ABCD matrix:
[image]

So I'm supposed to solve for the reflection coefficient $$\Gamma_1$$ and the current I flowing through the resistor R. The characteristic impedance $$Z_0=50\Omega$$ .

I first solved for the wave length from $$\lambda=\frac{v}{f}$$

which is $$\frac{3}{2}$$ using speed of light.
[image]

Then solving for bl for the matrix with the ABCD parameters you get
$$\beta l_1 = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}l_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and $$\beta l_2 = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}l_2=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

Since the end of the second line is left open $$I_b=0$$ So now we want to solve for $$Z_{in2}=\frac{U_a}{I_a}$$
First $$U_a=cos(\beta l_2)U_b$$ and $$I_a=j\frac{1}{Z_0}sin(\beta l_2)U_b$$
Then for the impedance we get $$Z_{in2}=\frac{U_a}{I_a}=\frac{cos(\beta l_2)}{j\frac{1}{Z_0}sin(\beta l_2)}=\frac{50cos(\frac{\pi}{4})}{jsin(\frac{\pi}{4})}=-j50$$

So now this impedance is in parallel with $$Z_L=20+j40$$ so we calculate the parallel connection
$$Z=\frac{Z_LZ_{in2}}{Z_L+Z_{in2}}=100$$
Now for the reflection constant $$\Gamma_1=\frac{Z-Z_0}{Z+Z_0}\frac{1}{3}$$

So now to solve for the current flowing through the resistor we know the first transmission line is ended by the impedance $$100$$, which I solved above. Now we solve for $$Z_{in1}=\frac{Zcos(\beta l_1)+jZ_0sin(\beta l_1)}{jZ\frac{1}{Z_0}sin(\beta l_1)+cos(\beta l_1)}$$ for which I get $$99.8-j4.1$$ Now the current can be solved using ohms law $$I=\frac{E}{R+Z_{in1}}=0.0075+j1.02$$

Answer (score 0):

Study of a mismatched line with a stub :
[image]